# Get max id from grouping two columns as pair

Tags: group-by, max, mariadb-10.3

i have search a lot to find a solution to get the max id using group by of two columns as a pair in a data set but none of the queries i have found and used worked as expected. Below is an example data set:

| id | tour_id | p1 | stage | rnd | assoc1 | p2 | assoc2 | winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 996057 | 5277 | 107028 | Main Draw | 32 | GER | 110673 | IRI | 107028 |
| 996101 | 5277 | 107028 | Main Draw | 16 | GER | 105136 | FRA | 107028 |
| 996126 | 5277 | 107028 | Main Draw | 8 | GER | 112074 | SWE | 107028 |
| 996133 | 5277 | 107028 | Main Draw | 4 | GER | 123980 | JPN | 107028 |
| 996139 | 5277 | 107028 | Main Draw | 2 | GER | 121582 | TPE | 107028 |
| 996037 | 5277 | 116620 | Main Draw | 32 | GER | 121582 | TPE | 121582 |
| 996037 | 5277 | 121582 | Main Draw | 32 | TPE | 116620 | GER | 121582 |
| 996097 | 5277 | 121582 | Main Draw | 16 | TPE | 104314 | IND | 121582 |
| 996121 | 5277 | 121582 | Main Draw | 8 | TPE | 112092 | NGR | 121582 |
| 996132 | 5277 | 121582 | Main Draw | 4 | TPE | 112062 | FRA | 121582 |
| 996139 | 5277 | 121582 | Main Draw | 2 | TPE | 107028 | GER | 107028 |
| 996324 | 5278 | 107028 | Main Draw | 32 | GER | 100439 | EGY | 107028 |
| 996362 | 5278 | 107028 | Main Draw | 16 | GER | 104314 | IND | 107028 |
| 996379 | 5278 | 107028 | Main Draw | 8 | GER | 116853 | SWE | 107028 |
| 996390 | 5278 | 107028 | Main Draw | 4 | GER | 123980 | JPN | 123980 |
| 996283 | 5278 | 116620 | Main Draw | 64 | GER | 121514 | KOR | 121514 |
| 996313 | 5278 | 121582 | Main Draw | 32 | TPE | 106296 | POR | 121582 |
| 996357 | 5278 | 121582 | Main Draw | 16 | TPE | 102968 | AUT | 121582 |
| 996380 | 5278 | 121582 | Main Draw | 8 | TPE | 102761 | GER | 102761 |
| 998765 | 5299 | 101222 | Main Draw | 64 | GER | 118671 | DEN | 101222 |
| 998788 | 5299 | 101222 | Main Draw | 32 | GER | 102380 | ENG | 101222 |
| 998801 | 5299 | 101222 | Main Draw | 16 | GER | 116620 | GER | 101222 |
| 998807 | 5299 | 101222 | Main Draw | 8 | GER | 116853 | SWE | 101222 |
| 998810 | 5299 | 101222 | Main Draw | 4 | GER | 112074 | SWE | 101222 |
| 998812 | 5299 | 101222 | Main Draw | 2 | GER | 107028 | GER | 101222 |
| 998773 | 5299 | 107028 | Main Draw | 64 | GER | 120168 | TUR | 107028 |
| 998797 | 5299 | 107028 | Main Draw | 32 | GER | 102891 | CRO | 107028 |
| 998805 | 5299 | 107028 | Main Draw | 16 | GER | 104379 | SWE | 107028 |
| 998809 | 5299 | 107028 | Main Draw | 8 | GER | 104036 | CZE | 107028 |
| 998811 | 5299 | 107028 | Main Draw | 4 | GER | 102841 | POR | 107028 |
| 998812 | 5299 | 107028 | Main Draw | 2 | GER | 101222 | GER | 101222 |
| 998757 | 5299 | 116620 | Main Draw | 64 | GER | 101192 | ITA | 116620 |
| 998794 | 5299 | 116620 | Main Draw | 32 | GER | 115449 | AUT | 116620 |
| 998801 | 5299 | 116620 | Main Draw | 16 | GER | 101222 | GER | 101222 |

What I would like to get is the following output which is basically the max(id) of the grouping of p1 and tour_id

| id | tour_id | p1 | stage | rnd | assoc1 | p2 | assoc2 | winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 996139 | 5277 | 107028 | Main Draw | 2 | GER | 121582 | TPE | 107028 |
| 996037 | 5277 | 116620 | Main Draw | 32 | GER | 121582 | TPE | 121582 |
| 996139 | 5277 | 121582 | Main Draw | 2 | TPE | 107028 | GER | 107028 |
| 996390 | 5278 | 107028 | Main Draw | 4 | GER | 123980 | JPN | 123980 |
| 996283 | 5278 | 116620 | Main Draw | 64 | GER | 121514 | KOR | 121514 |
| 996380 | 5278 | 121582 | Main Draw | 8 | TPE | 102761 | GER | 102761 |
| 998812 | 5299 | 101222 | Main Draw | 2 | GER | 107028 | GER | 101222 |
| 998812 | 5299 | 107028 | Main Draw | 2 | GER | 101222 | GER | 101222 |
| 998801 | 5299 | 116620 | Main Draw | 16 | GER | 101222 | GER | 101222 |

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I would take a simple query to get the max id for the conditions, and then either use it as a subquery or join, depending on the use case.  Take a look at this fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/K1wM0gEK

I've inserted your data and then a series of queries.  Here's the first one, just to get the maxID for each combination of tour_id and p1:

```
select tour_id, p1, max(id) as maxID 
from t group by tour_id, p1;
```

which you can then use in a subquery to retrieve any rows that match those IDs like so:

```
select * from t
where id in (
  select max(id)
  from t group by tour_id, p1
);
```

or as a JOIN:

```
select t.* from t
join (
  select max(id) as maxID
  from t group by tour_id, p1
) ids on t.id = ids.maxID;
```

JOINs are usually more performant than IN for larger data sets, but that is not a hard and fast rule and the line really isn't well defined.  I've included it here just for reference.

Now, these queries SHOULD be returning the same results, but it seems that the ID you're fetching the max value for isn't a unique ID, so they aren't, and it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish as to which answer is right.  Here's one more option using window functions, which are really overkill for this, but let's look:

```
select tour_id, p1, 
  first_value(id) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as maxID,
  first_value(stage) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as stage,
  first_value(rnd) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as rnd,
  first_value(assoc1) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as assoc1,
  first_value(p2) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as p2,
  first_value(assoc2) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as assoc2,
  first_value(winner) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as winner
from t
```

Now this returns a LOT more rows, but a lot of them are duplicates, so let's add DISTINCT to just get the uniques:

```
select DISTINCT tour_id, p1, 
  first_value(id) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as maxID,
  first_value(stage) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as stage,
  first_value(rnd) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as rnd,
  first_value(assoc1) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as assoc1,
  first_value(p2) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as p2,
  first_value(assoc2) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as assoc2,
  first_value(winner) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as winner
from t
```

and now we're down to something that looks a little more like what you were after.  For comparison, I have included the three queries side by side, ordered by id and with the columns all in the same order:

```
select DISTINCT 
  first_value(id) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as maxID,
  tour_id, p1, 
  first_value(stage) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as stage,
  first_value(rnd) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as rnd,
  first_value(assoc1) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as assoc1,
  first_value(p2) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as p2,
  first_value(assoc2) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as assoc2,
  first_value(winner) OVER (partition by tour_id, p1 order by id desc) as winner
from t order by 1;
  
select * from t
where id in (
  select max(id)
  from t group by tour_id, p1
) order by id;

select t.* from t
join (
  select max(id) as maxID
  from t group by tour_id, p1
) ids on t.id = ids.maxID
order by t.id;
```

The result set using the window functions seems to have the same output as you're looking for, but let me say that it seems like window functions are overkill for a case this simple, so I'm wondering if you need some unique ID instead.  If you don't have a unique primary (autoincrementing) ID in your table(s), you should.  It will save you a lot of headache at some point down the road.  If you do, I wonder why we aren't using that instead of the non-unique one.

Let me know if this helps, or if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and the detailed explanation. The reason i dont have a unique id is that the data set is populated from view which is populated using union because i need to group by 'p1' but actually 'p2' should be also in the same column so that i include all possibilities. That's why there are duplicates like id: 996037. If there is a simpler solution to get a unique id I would be happy to follow.

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like to get the results for combinations of tour_id, p1 and p2?

Comment: No. The combination is fine. What I am saying is that the initial db table with the 'id' a primary key is structured as: id, tour_id, player1, player2 etc which represents the results of player1 vs player2 in a tournament. In order to achieve the group by tournament and player I need to duplicate using union all so that I get the the pair as tour_id / player1 but also as tour_id / player2. I hope you understood the logic.

Comment: Do you have control over the view?  If so, I believe you could add a unique identifier in the view, for instance a row number.

Comment: Maybe using use concat to create a Unique ID using the current id + p1 or p2 per case. This will create a numeric unique identifier in the view. Could it be a solution?

Comment: You need something autoincrementing like a row number so you can order by it.  If I understand what you're trying to do with the view, which I might not.  I don't have any data about it, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: As long as the decisive factor is the max)id) in order to get the last result of the dataset for the pair tour_id / player i dont think that making an autonumber unique id could return the desired outcome. If the result could return unique records for tour_id and p1 or tour_id and p2 then the view is not needed.

Comment: If for each combination of tour_id and player there are multiple records with the same id, but you know which one you want (and you seem to), then you can sort them somehow so that the one you want is last (or first) and then an autogenerated id (like a row number) would let you pick out that one using a simple query.  Consider that you keep saying you want the "max id".  That implies some kind of sort already.  I also doubt that a view is necessary, I just don't have enough information about your data and problem to do anything but guess.